# duplicacy in Switch button

Tags: android, android-switch

hello i am new to android development i am making an applock application in which i am using  switch to lock/unlock application...i am facing a problem in switch.

when ever i toggle any switch "on" on the list of applications to lock exactly 11th one from the current switch also gets "on" and its continues till the end of the list....means i only toggle one switch on bt i find many switches on and when ever i puts any one off all the switches turns off..

i am not getting where i am making the mistake

my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:layout_width="50dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_weight="2"

        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
       android:layout_weight="1"

        android:gravity="right"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my java code...

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    Switch s;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list =(ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,0); 

        final ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(this, R.layout.activity_main, list)

            {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if (convertView == null)
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);


                final String text = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

                ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

                final Drawable drawable = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
                ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable(drawable);

                 s= (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

                return convertView;
            }
            };
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        if(s!=null)
        {

            s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }

}
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean ischecked) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Monitored switch is " + (ischecked ? "on" : "off"),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: I can see how you create one switch in your code. I suppose the LinearLayout is one item in the list of applications? Could you add how you create the list?

Comment: you would need to maintain as to which switch(or list item) was toggled

Comment: i have posted my java code...in this code also "OnCheckedChange" is not working..